# Java 8 Ignore "filter" if filters list is empty

Tags: java, java-stream

for example:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cat> cats = //Get cats somwhere;
        List<String> favoriteNames = {"Bella", "Leo"};
        cats.stream()
            .filter(cat -> favoriteNames.stream().anyMatch(Cat::getName::equalsIgnoreCase))
            .filter(/*Any other filter*/)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class Cat {
    String name;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I want to have cats only with `favoriteNames` (if it is not empty) or all of them in case `favoriteNames` is empty. Then I want to do any other things (for example select only old cats).
Current example (if I not make a misprint in `Predicate`) will filter out all cats if there is not any favorite names.
How to do what I want by using streams?

Comment: You could use `favouriteNames.isEmpty() || ....` in your filter. Or store this in a variable outside the stream and then use that variable

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `if else` condition here to check favoriteNames list if it's empty or not ?

Comment: You can use a Java code inside the .filter. For example cat -> {if something else otherthing}

Comment: @GauthamM sotmething like this:
.filter(cat -> favoriteNames.isEmpty() || favoriteNames.stream().anyMatch(Cat::getName::equalsIgnoreCase) ?

Comment: Damn, realy.. It just predicate... I can do inside what I want.

Comment: @RiseOfDeath Yes. or you could extract that `favoriteNames.isEmpty` value to a `boolean` outside the stream and use that variable in the stream.

Comment: But probably you want to use `Set<String> favoriteNames = new TreeSet<>(String .CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` … `.filter(cat -> favoriteNames.isEmpty() || favoriteNames.contains(cat.getName()))` instead of performing a linear search for each cat.

Comment: @Holger Will stream (or parallelStream) for Tree be faster then for ArrayList?
Is it there big difference for f.e. 100-300 cats and 0-20 favorite names?

Comment: The performance of a parallel stream mainly depends on the source you’re streaming over, i.e. for `cats.stream()` the type of `cats` which is a `List` in either case, which is very efficient (assuming you’re not using `LinkedList`). Using a `TreeSet` for `favoriteNames` is more efficient for larger `favoriteNames`, whether you’re using a parallel stream or not. For twenty favorite names, using a `TreeSet` may already pay off, though it’s still a very small number, hence, taking almost no time anyway. And 300 cats is way too little to justify the use of a parallel stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Cat> cats = List.of(new Cat("たま", 3), new Cat("しろ", 2));
    List<String> favoriteNames = List.of();
    List<Cat> favoriteCats = cats.stream()
        .filter(cat -> favoriteNames.isEmpty() || favoriteNames.contains(cat.getName()))
        .toList();
    System.out.println(favoriteCats);
}
```

output:

```
 [Cat(name=たま, age=3), Cat(name=しろ, age=2)]
```

or

```
    var stream = cats.stream();
    if (!favoriteNames.isEmpty())
        stream = stream.filter(cat -> favoriteNames.contains(cat.getName()));
    List<Cat> favoriteCats = stream.toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public List<Cat> filterCats(List<Cat> input, List<String> favouriteNames) {
        return input.stream()
                .filter(cat -> favouriteNames.size() == 0 || favouriteNames.contains(cat.getName()))
                .filter(cat -> cat.getAge() > 5)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Where `cat.getAge() > 5` is an example of an additional filter.

Answer (score -1):

```
 List<Cat> cats = //Get cats somwhere;
        List<String> favoriteNames = {"Bella", "Leo"};
        cats.stream()
            .filter(cat -> {
               if(favoriteNames.stream().anyMatch(Cat::getName::equalsIgnoreCase))){ 
                 return //any filter if true;}               
               else {
                 return cat.getId()!=null;  //return back the whole list cuz id is always present}    
            .filter(/*Any other filter*/)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

hope this help